# Apache proxypass and multilingual domains

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, mod-proxy-html

I have a website on domain.com which has multilingual content in URLs e.g.:

- domain.com/en for english
- domain.com/de for german
- domain.com/it for italian

etc. These are not really directories - these are just rewrites that rewrite to /index.php?lang=... So domain.com/lang/one/two/three is rewritten to /index.php?lang=$1&path=$2

It also has domain.com/assets directory that holds all the common files (css, images etc.)

Now I want to change that every language has its own domain which I think could be managed by using mod_proxy, mod_proxy_http and mod_proxy_html in Apache. What I want to achieve is that if user visits:

- www.domain.com he gets content from domain.com/en
- www.domain.de he gets content from domain.com/de
- www.domain.it he gets content from domain.com/it

And if he visits /assets directory from any domain (.com, .de, .it) he would get content from domain.com/assets. Also if user visits URL e.g. www.domain.de/something he should receive content from www.domain.com/de/something

And the other thing are URLs which would have to be rewritten before output so for instance user that browses domain.de would never go to domain.com at all...

Is this possible? Otherwise we would have to reprogram whole CMS to work with different domain for every language...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Just handle them in a single virtualhost and use RewriteCond to examine %{HTTP_HOST} and do the same rewrites you're already doing today.  You can capture the country code and backreference it with %1.

Comment: the problem is that CMS produces all internal links (including css & js) with full www.domain.com/lang/..... URLs. If we want CMS to produce www.domain.lang URLs instead we would have to rewrite whole CMS. That's why I am looking for a solution that would also change all URLs in HTML document to correct domain and from what I read over the internet apache's mod_proxy_html does that - but I can't configure it, whatever I tried was not working